# Install Zend Debugger or Xdebug for PHP 7.0 on RedHat 6.10 (64bit)

Tags: centos, php, redhat, centos6, xdebug

I'm trying to install Zend Debugger or Xdebug on RedHat 6.10 for PHP 7.0.

I have tried the Zend Debugger extension for PHP 7.0 provided by Zend.com at http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/downloads-studio#Linux, but it appears that requires RedHat 7.

I would be fine using Xdebug instead, but I'm unclear which release(s) if any is compatible with both RedHat 6 and PHP 7.0.

Comment: Where did you get PHP from?

Comment: Red Hat Software Collections

Comment: Then you must get XDebug from the same Software Collection, e.g. `rh-php70-php-xdebug`.